# How can we remove one solid color from an Image?

Tags: opencv

Using the cvSet method we can easily fill an image with solid colours. 
Is there any method which can help you remove some colours from ur image
(e.g I have an Image of a forest. Basically it will have a lot of green component, leaves etc. Can I remove the green color keeping everything else same.)

Comment: What do you mean by "remove them"? Set them to 0?

Comment: Why isn't saving a temporary copy of the image, and restoring from it, an option?

Comment: My example might be ambiguous. Suppose I have an Image of forest. I load it. If I use cvSet to 0 will it remove the green component?

Comment: Maybe you can show us some images to describe what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    char* inputPath = "TEST.png";

    Mat src = imread(inputPath);
    Mat BGRChannels[3];
    split(src,BGRChannels); // split the BGR channesl
    BGRChannels[1]=Mat::zeros(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1);// removing Green channel
    merge(BGRChannels,3,src); // pack the image 
    namedWindow("B0R",1);
    imshow("B0R",src);
    waitKey(0);
```

Here is the result:
[image: main image]

[image: removed green channel image]

Comment: there is simpler way : `src = src - Scalar(0,255,0);`

Comment: @sturkmen, yeah this also cancels out the green plane in 8-bit plane RGB image.